# Set Signing Options of Enterprise Application using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

does anyone of you know how I can set the 'Signing Option' of an azure enterprise app single sign-on to 'Sign SAML response and assertion' using the Graph API?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Microsoft Graph API to set the 'Signing Option' of an azure enterprise app single sign-on, please refer to the following steps

1. Get the azure enterprise app token Issuance Policy

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<the enterprise app object id>/tokenIssuancePolicies
```

[image]

2. Update token Issuance Policy

```
Patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenIssuancePolicies/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "definition":["{\r\n  \"TokenIssuancePolicy\": {\r\n    \"Version\": 1,\r\n    \"SigningAlgorithm\": \"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256\",\r\n    \"TokenResponseSigningPolicy\": \"ResponseAndToken\",\r\n    \"SamlTokenVersion\": \"2.0\"\r\n  }\r\n}"]
 
}
```

[image]
The origin setting
[image]

The new setting
[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/tokenissuancepolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties-of-a-token-issuance-policy-definition) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list-tokenissuancepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)